# How to override predefined function in Scala?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, overriding

I need to implement function `to`. I have the following working code:

```
object Main {

  val m = 0
  val km = 1

  implicit def wrapM(v: Int) = new {
    def m = v
  }

  implicit def wrapKm(v: Int) = new {
    def km = v * 1000
  }

  implicit class toWrap(fromVal: Int) {
    def too (value: Int): Double = {
      if (value.equals(km)) {
        fromVal / 1000.0
      } else {
        0
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args:Array[String])
  {
    println(53.m too km)
  }
}
```

But there is one problem. I use `too` name, instead of `to`. If I rename it to `to`, then I get the error:

```
Error:(30, 16) type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: ?{def to(x$1: ? >: Int): ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method intWrapper in class LowPriorityImplicits of type (x: Int)scala.runtime.RichInt
 and method toWrap in object Main of type (fromVal: Int)Main.toWrap
 are possible conversion functions from Int to ?{def to(x$1: ? >: Int): ?}
    println(53.m to km)
               ^
```

It is due to the fact, that there is one other function `to` - `scala.runtime.RichInt#to`.

Comment: scala does not allow define two implicits with same arguments set in one context.

Comment: @Mr.V., yeah, I know about it. But maybe there is a way to hide that `to` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala does not allow define two implicits with same arguments set in one context....

But there is a way. You should work with different type in `toWrap` implicit , instead of standard scala `Int`.

Check sample below.
My idea is to implement method `to` for some wrapper class `IntWrap` instead of standard `Int`

```
 case class IntWrap(v: Int)  {

  }

  val m = 0
  val km = 1

  implicit def wrapM(v: Int) = new {
    def m = IntWrap(v)
  }

  implicit def wrapKm(v: Int) = new {
    def km = v * 1000
  }

  implicit class toWrap(fromVal: IntWrap) {
    def to(value: Int): Double = {
      if (value.equals(km)) {
        fromVal.v / 1000.0
      } else {
        0
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args:Array[String])
  {

    println(53.m to km)
  }
```